# Is the "method of undetermined co-coefficients" the same as the "annihilator method"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I heard my professor refer to it as the "annihilator", but I also see conflicting definitions. Could anyone clarify if these two methods are popularly referred to are the same? If they're different, what are the differences?

Comment: Undetermined coefficients usually involves plugging in a generic form and then solving for constants, whereas the annihilator method relies on re-phrasing the question in terms of differential operators. So no, I think they are completely different.

Comment: @user140943 Do you know any good literature on where to read up on the Annihilator method, per chance?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. They are actually quite similar. I thought you were talking about using differential operators to find the solutions. Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method It shows the similarity well.

Comment: And if you just want to learn about ODE's in general, the book "Ordinary Differential Equations" by by Morris Tenenbaum, Harry Pollard published by Dover is excellent. You can find it on amazon

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I normally skip over Wikipedia as I find the explanations too terse sometimes... but this time it was right underneath my nose. Feel free to right up an answer for future visitors and 15 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undetermined coefficients usually involves plugging in a generic form and then solving for constants, whereas the annihilator method relies on re-phrasing the question in terms of differential operators. They are fairly similar as this page shows:  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method.

And if you just want to learn about ODE's in general, the book "Ordinary Differential Equations" by by Morris Tenenbaum, Harry Pollard published by Dover is excellent. You can find it on amazon.